# how can i define a maintenance template within a custom module?

Tags: 7, theming

i have done this within a module for defining custom templates when having status error

```
function custom_module_preprocess_region(&$vars) {

  $header = drupal_get_http_header('status');

  if( $vars['region'] == 'content' ) {
if ($header == '404 Not Found') {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'content__404';     
}
if ($header == '403 Forbidden')  {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'content__403';
}
 }
 }

 function custom_module_theme() {
   return array(
'content__404' => array(
  'template' => 'region--content--404',
  'variables' => array('xxx' => null),
  'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module').'/templates'
),
'content__403' => array(
  'template' => 'region--content--403',
  'variables' => array('xxx' => null),
  'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module').'/templates'
),
'maintenance' => array(
  'template' => 'region--content--maintenance',
  'variables' => array('xxx' => null),
  'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module').'/templates'
),
 );
 }
```

How can i implement it just the same to override the theme maintenance tpl ?

Comment: Is it for D7 or D8?

Comment: sorry i should have precised for D7

Answer (score 1):

**drupal_get_http_header()** *should be treated as deprecated.*

See https://www.drupal.org/node/1969270#comment-7609337

I think your approach is good, but for a little more coverage of 404/403 pages we came up with a more extendable approach, also theres a bit more room for customization in the backend within the modules settings page.

We did this by using the **customerror module** in conjunction with a theme function and a few overriding template files.

https://www.drupal.org/project/customerror

After installing, add this to your **template.php** file's *theme_preprocess_page* function. Example;

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  $alias_parts = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias());

  if (count($alias_parts) && $alias_parts[0] == 'customerror') {
    if ($alias_parts[1] == '403') {
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__forbidden';
    }
    if ($alias_parts[1] == '404') {
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__not_found';
    }
  }

  <other code goes here>

}
```

Then in your **templates** folder add your custom templates (just like your page.tpl.php file);

- **page--forbidden.tpl.php**
- **page--not-found.tpl.php**

Clear your cache, hit one of those pages (you can test them by going to);

- **[yoursite]/customerror/403**
- **[yoursite]/customerror/404**

As for your maintenance page, all you need to do is create a 
**maintenance-page.tpl.php** file and toss that in your templates folder.

Comment: i am trying to have all code contained in the module, for multisites purpose